# SQL to LINQ with left join and group

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq

I created a worked sql query:

```
select CONVERT(date, C.tDate) as dt, count(O.Id) as cnt  from [Calendar] C
left outer join [Order] O
on C.tDate = CONVERT(date, O.Dt)
group by CONVERT(date, C.tDate)
order by CONVERT(date, C.tDate)
```

And I want to rewrite it use LINQ:

```
var res = (from c in db.Calendars
join o in db.Orders on c.tDate equals DbFunctions.TruncateTime(o.Dt.Value) into pp
from pl in pp.DefaultIfEmpty()
group c by DbFunctions.TruncateTime(pl.Dt.Value) into g
orderby g.FirstOrDefault().tDate
select new { date = g.FirstOrDefault().tDate, cnt = g.Count() }).ToList();
```

I get all rows from calendar in sql query, but only not null rows (right part) in LINQ query.
How can I get all calendar's rows in LINQ.

Added:
Then I try:

```
var res = (from c in db.Calendars
join o in db.Orders on c.tDate equals DbFunctions.TruncateTime(o.Dt.Value) into pp
from o in pp.DefaultIfEmpty()
group pp by DbFunctions.TruncateTime(o.Dt) into g2
select new { date = g2.Key, cnt = g2.Count() }).ToList();
```

And I see this one:

```
{ date = null, cnt = 1062 } 
{ date = {25.01.2019}, cnt = 4 }
{ date = {26.01.2019}, cnt = 7 }
{ date = {27.01.2019}, cnt = 16 }
{ date = {28.01.2019}, cnt = 5 }
```

I want to get all dates instead null...

Comment: Use pp instead of c in the group

Comment: I try it, no changes...

Comment: I think the "from" in third line should have `o` instead of `pl`. Then fourth line would get `o` instead of `pl`

Comment: pl is also wrong.  It should be o.  See Left Outer Join : https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

Comment: Perhaps my [SQL to LINQ Recipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49245160/sql-to-linq-with-multiple-join-count-and-left-join/49245786#49245786) might prove useful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one:

```
var res = (from c in db.Calendars
join o in db.Orders on c.tDate equals DbFunctions.TruncateTime(o.Dt.Value) into pp
from o in pp.DefaultIfEmpty()
group pp by DbFunctions.TruncateTime(c.tDate) into g2
orderby g2.Key
select new { date = g2.Key, cnt = g2.FirstOrDefault().Count() }).ToList();
```